# 18.04: NFS4 over Kerberos fails

Tags: 18.04, nfs, kerberos

On a 18.04-client NFS4 over Kerberos is fine against an old ubuntu 10.04 nfs4-server. It would not work however against a Netapp FAS3140 (which is accessible from 14.04 clients).

```
client_18.04_# mount -v netapp:/resource  /mont/netapp-res -t nfs4 -o sec=krb5
mount.nfs4: timeout set for Thu Aug  2 10:13:25 2018
mount.nfs4: trying text-based options 'sec=krb5,vers=4.2,addr=xxxx,clientaddr=yyyy'
mount.nfs4: mount(2): Protocol not supported
mount.nfs4: trying text-based options 'sec=krb5,vers=4.1,addr=xxxx,clientaddr=yyyy'
mount.nfs4: mount(2): Protocol not supported
mount.nfs4: trying text-based options 'sec=krb5,vers=4.0,addr=xxxx,clientaddr=yyyy'
mount.nfs4: mount(2): Permission denied

client_18.04_# klist  /tmp/krb5ccmachine_... # shows a krbtgt only, no nfs ticket
```

This applies to Ubuntu Kernel 4.15.0-20-generic and 4.15.0-29-generic (amd64). **vanilla kernel 4.14.0 is fine.**

How can I help to trace this kind of error?

Comment: What does `rpcinfo 10.162.229.2` show? Are you sure "vers" needs a decimal point? The error points to "protocol" so the "vers" option.  I almost only see "vers=2", "vers=3" or "vers=4" in all my setups even when the version has a point release.

Comment: Unfortunately /etc/default/nfs-common only allows to distniguish between  nfs2 , nfs3, nfs4 (see   https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039343/nfs4-18-04-client-force-nfs-ver-4-0-ldap-map-multiple-client-versions) Still there is  nfs4.2, nfs4.1, nfs4.0.   the output of  "mount  -v -t nfs4  ..."  tells that all of three are probed automatically. handshake seems to work with nfs4.0 but authentication with the kernel module fails.

Comment: rpcinfo sais:
...
    100003    4    tcp       0.0.0.0.8.1            nfs        unknown
    100003    3    tcp       0.0.0.0.8.1            nfs        unknown
...